# Does NTFS write in the background?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, ntfs

Does NTFS do any writing in the background when the user is not writing any data?  Does it do any writing after the write/copy dialog reaches 100% and closes?  I've seen claims that it does this because of its journaling features.  I am concerned that if this is the case, this means unplugging without unmounting an NTFS USB drive can cause problems.  The drive in question is configured for "Quick removal".

Comment: "NTFS" doesn't do anything, it is a file system type. You need to check what the OS you are using does while operating on a NTFS drive. ;)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto is right. This might depend on the OS.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, indeed. See for instance *Carrier, File System Forensic Analysis.*

Answer (score 1):

Not only NTFS, but hardware can (and *does*) perform some delayed (cached) writes after UI shows you nothing more goes on.

If you do remove your drive "properly", with 'unmount' option, you can expect at least OS doesn't have anything cached to write (if you trust Microsoft on this). Next, you can ask yourself do you trust manufacturer of  specific hardware you use (and corresponding device firmware) - whether it exposes the real state of device and whether combination of hardware / firmware & OS drivers reflect real state of data.

Comment: From what I understand, setting the policy in Device Manager to "Quick removal" rather than "Better performance" disables cached writes on the device and in Windows.  So would NTFS still do writing in the background in "Quick removal" configuration?

Comment: It will try to disable OS-level cache writes (still you cannot be sure it is handled by hardware drivers same way). Firmware still can handle such requests it's own way.
For example, any HDD caches some data in internal buffer despite of what, as long as writing it onto the disk is not immediate by design

Comment: There is some delay for mechanical (i.e. HDD) hardware, introduced by design, between write command reaches the HW controller and data is actually written on magnetic disc.
It works most of time, and designed to handle power outages, but you cannot be absolutely sure of it